# How to avoid cycling imports when splitting __init__.py into multiple files

Tags: python

Lets say I am starting from an ugly `__init__.py` file in my module:

```
def a():
  print("this is awesome")

def b():
  print("An opinion:")
  a()

b()
```

Functions `a` and `b` are cool, but I want them to move out into separate files. While still being available in to the module consumer from module root. What do I do?

I expect something along the lines:

```
### __init__.py
from a import a
from b import b

b()
```

```
### a.py
def a():
  print("this is awesome")
```

```
### b.py
import a
def b():
  print("An opinion:")
  a.a()
```

```
### client code

import awesome_module

awesome_module.a()
awesome_module.b()
```

Which results in `No module named 'a'` on the init file. How do I do that right? But more importantly, where do I learn more about these things?

**Update:** and what do I do if I want to call b() in `__init__.py` but not have b() available through module import to the end user?

Comment: In `__init__.py`, use `from .a import a`

Comment: @JohnGordon Is there a preference between `from awesome_module.a import a` and `from .a imoprt a` ?

Comment: `from .a import a` is a little cleaner, because you don't have to worry if `awesome_module` is eventually renamed to something else.

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit" from PEP 20 would suggest `from awesome_module.a import a`. And PEP 8 explicitly states a preference for absolute imports over relative ones. @John Gordon mentions just one of many possible refactoring scenarios. It's also possible that files are moved between modules, in which case relative imports are more likely to break. At the end of the day any good IDE will handle whatever refactoring tasks you give it.